# ical4j DateTime parse exception

Tags: android, datetime, ical4j

Using ical4j 1.0.6, I'm trying to instantiate a DateTime from a "DTSTART..." String. The constructor is throwing a ParserException even for the examples listed as valid in the [DateTime documentation](http://build.mnode.org/projects/ical4j/apidocs/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/DateTime.html) and [ical4j wiki](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/wiki/DateTime)

```
      String date = "DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:19970714T133000";
      try {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //always thrown
      }

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:19970714T133000" (at offset 0)
```

I've tried setting KEY_RELAXED_PARSING to true, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the javadoc, the constructor [DateTime(String)](http://build.mnode.org/projects/ical4j/apidocs/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/DateTime.html#DateTime(java.lang.String)) says:

> Constructs a new DateTime instance from parsing the specified string representation **in the default (local) timezone**.

So I guess the "DSTART" and "TZID" parts of the string are too much.

To set a specific TimeZone, read the section [Working with timezones](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html).

Comment: No, I'm sure you can't be. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code

```
      String[] parts = property.split(":");
      if (parts.length > 1) {
        try {
          String timezone = parts[0].replace("DTSTART;TZID=", "");

          DtStart start = new DtStart();
          start.getParameters().add(Value.DATE_TIME);
          start.getParameters().add(new TzId(timezone));
          start.setValue(parts[1]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```